# Is a corrupted HD a sign of something ominous for the hardware?

Tags: mac, hard-drive

The Verify Disk functionality of the Disk Utility reports that my HD is corrupted. I fixed the problem using the startup CD but what does that mean for the health of my HDD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One time error usually means nothing.

Do use it as a warning - keep your backups current and perhaps even test a restore. Also, you might check things in a week to make sure it's not a sign of hardware errors instead of a software error.

Comment: If backups are current and reliable, sometimes it's a good idea to start up from a backup, reformat and re-partition the HDD to make sure you've got things set up the way you want them and then backup the backup back over the HDD.